# "resources"-directory for ruby gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-c-extension

I'm currently experimenting with creating my own gem in Ruby. The gem requires some static resources (say an icon in ICO format). Where do I put such resources within my gem directory tree and how to I access them from code?

Also, parts of my extension are native C code and I would like the C-parts to have access to the resources too.

Comment: Ok, I found a way to do it by using __FILE__ from within the ruby code, but this seems rather dirty to me...

Comment: Yeah, that's what I would have done. There's not really another good way :/ (at least, that I can think of; I could be wrong)

Comment: Do you want a way to cleanly access the gem's files that are outside of the `lib` directory, or are you looking for an object-oriented way to work with your resources?

Answer (score 9):

You can put resources anywhere you want, except in the `lib` directory. Since it will be will be part of Ruby's load path, the only files that should be there are the ones that you want people to `require`.

For example, I usually store translated text in the `i18n/` directory. For icons, I'd just put them in `resources/icons/`.

As for how to *access* these resources... I ran into this problem enough that [I wrote a little gem](https://github.com/matheusmoreira/jewel) just to avoid repetition.

Basically, I was doing this all the time:

```
def Your::Gem.root
  # Current file is /home/you/code/your/lib/your/gem.rb
  File.expand_path '../..', File.dirname(__FILE__)
end

Your::Gem.root
# => /home/you/code/your/
```

I wrapped this up into a nice DSL, added some additional convenience stuff and ended up with this:

```
class Your::Gem < Jewel::Gem
  root '../..'
end

root = Your::Gem.root
# => /home/you/code/your/

# No more joins!
path = root.resources.icons 'your.ico'
# => /home/you/code/your/resources/icons/your.ico
```

As for accessing your resources in C, `path` is just a [`Pathname`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html). You can pass it to a C function as a string, open the file and just do what you need to do. You can even return an object to the Ruby world:

```
VALUE your_ico_new(VALUE klass, VALUE path) {
    char * ico_file = NULL;
    struct your_ico * ico = NULL;

    ico_file = StringValueCStr(path);
    ico = your_ico_load_from_file(ico_file); /* Implement this */
    return Data_Wrap_Struct(your_ico_class, your_ico_mark, your_ico_free, ico);
}
```

Now you can access it from Ruby:

```
ico = Your::Ico.new path
```